# What is a simple way to use websockets in Node.js WITHOUT a library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I want a simple socket connection, where the server should tell the client the total amount of connections (whenever a connection happens), and the client should update the DOM. I feel like socket.io or any other library is too full featured for such a simple reason. Any idea how to do this without libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js documentation shows a very good example how to communicate using Sockets without libraries: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade

Socket.io is not too 'full featured'. It's quite minimalistic and makes everything works with much less pain. I really recommend you trying it.

Comment: I have used it, it is just a little heavy for what I need. Thanks :)